# How do I wait until a bool is true in unity?

Tags: c#, yield-return

I am trying to make it so that when a button is pressed, the text would update.

My code:

```
public Text TextField;

public bool narrationGoing = true;

public void SetText(string text)
{
    TextField.text = text;
}

public void ResumeNarration()
{
    narrationGoing=true;
}

IEnumerator WaitNarration()
{
    narrationGoing = false;
    Debug.Log(narrationGoing);
    yield return new WaitWhile(() => narrationGoing == false);
}

void Start()
{
    Narration();
}

void Narration()
{
    SetText("HeLlO wOrLd");
    StartCoroutine(WaitNarration());
    SetText("The button worked!");
}
```

However, when I launch the game it triggers the "WaitNarration()" coroutine, because it does write "false", but then it skips over the yield completely. I've tried to find a solution but sadly nothing worked, does anyone have an answer for how I can fix this? Thank you in advance!
Also, ResumeNarration() is a function for the button, that's why it's not triggered in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can yield inside of a while loop until the condition is met.

```
IEnumerator WaitNarration()
{
    Debug.Log("WaitNarration started");
    
    while (!narrationGoing)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    Debug.Log("WaitNarration complete");
}
```

Comment: I tried it, and it does debug.log “waitnarration complete” when I press the button, but it still changes the text to “the button worked!” BEFORE the button is pressed. Maybe it starts the coroutine and then continues with the main function? Thanks for helping by the way, and sorry if I’m just stupid.

Comment: That is correct, this is not stopping the main thread from running, it is essentially running in parallel to the main thread.  Place your SetText call inside of the coroutine if you want it affected by the delay.

Comment: thanks! I’ll try that, wouldn’t it trigger multiple SetText() Coroutines at the same time though? Or will it run them in order, so if I place a “narrationGoing = false;” after setting the text in SetText, it won’t immediately run the next SetText()?